# Sort ArrayList of objects by field in custom order

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

How can I achieve a custom sorting to the content of field name:

- first element: P followed by numbers [1-9]{2} always on first
- followed by  : P followed by numbers 0[0-9]
- followed by  : S
- followed by numbers [1-9]{2}
- and then the rest in normal order `i1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(i2.getName())`

  ```
  private static Comparator<Item> itemComperator = new Comparator<Item>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
          if (i1.getName().matches("P[1-9]{2}") && i2.getName().matches("P0[0-9]"))
              return -1;
          else if (i1.getName().matches("S[1-9]{2}"))
              return -1;
          else
              return i1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(i2.getName());
      }
  };

  @Test
  public void sortItem() {
      Item item01 = new Item(1, "R59");
      Item item02 = new Item(2, "S48");
      Item item03 = new Item(3, "P01");
      Item item04 = new Item(4, "P25");
      Item item05 = new Item(5, "R99");

      List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(item01, item02, item03, item04, item05);
      System.out.println("before sorting");
      long seed = System.nanoTime();
      Collections.shuffle(items, new Random(seed));
      for (Item i : items) {
          System.out.println(i.getId() + " " + i.getName());
      }

      System.out.println("after sorting");
      Collections.sort(items, itemComperator);
      for (Item i : items) {
          System.out.println(i.getId() + " " + i.getName());
      }


  }

  public class Item {
      private int id;
      private String name;

      public Item(int id, String name) {
          this.id = id;
          this.name = name;
      }

      public int getId() {
          return id;
      }

      public void setId(int id) {
          this.id = id;
      }

      public String getName() {
          return name;
      }

      public void setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
      }
  }
  ```

output expected:

```
after sorting
4 P25
3 P01
2 S48
1 R59
5 R99
```

Comment: Can you include the required out-put with the question .. ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that I would first map each of the inputs to a "kind" number, which is based upon the list of criteria above. For example:

```
int kind(String input) {
  if (input.matches("P[1-9]{2}") {
    return 0;
  } else if (input.matches("P0[0-9]")) {
    return 1;
  } else if (input.matches("S.*")) {
    return 2;
  } else if (input.matches("[1-9]{2}")) {
    return 3;
  } else {
    return 4;
  }
}
```

This gives you a way to see if the two strings are of the same "kind"; if not, return the ordering based on the kind. If they are the same kind, just compare them using (case insensitive) lexicographic ordering (you don't specify, but I assume you want e.g. "P11" to come before "P22"):

```
public int compare(Item a, Item b) {
  String nameA = a.getName();
  String nameB = b.getName();

  int kindA = kind(nameA);
  int kindB = kind(nameB);
  if (kindA != kindB) {
    return Integer.compare(kindA, kindB);
  } else {
    return nameA.compareToIgnoreCase(nameB);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `input.matches("S.*")` instead of `input.matches("S*")`?